# Generating matrix of MDS-code

Tags: self-learning, coding-theory

I'm trying to proof a fact about MDS-codes:
Linear $[n,k,d]_q$-code $K$ is MDS-code if and only if it has generating matrix of the form
$$ G_{k\times n}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3&\dots& a_d&0&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&b_1&b_2&\dots& b_{d-1}&b_d&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&c_1&\dots& c_{d-2}&c_{d-1}&c_d&0&\dots&0\\
\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots\\
0&0&0&\dots& 0&0&w_1&w_2&\dots&w_d\\
\end{pmatrix}_{k\times n},
a_i,b_i,c_i,w_i \not=0.
$$

I think it's clearly that if linear $[n,k,d]_q$-code $K$ has generating matrix $G_{k\times n}$ then it's MDS. But I have no idea how to proof the converse statement.

Comment: I don't think that the result you are trying to prove is true. Is this homework? or something that you came up with all by yourself?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, it's a homework.

Comment: Suggestion: Please add the `self-study` tag to your question.  Query:  So $c_d$ and $w_1$ are in the same _column_ of $G$? or is that an artifact from MathJax?

Comment: Maybe $\Rightarrow$ is true, but certainly not $\Leftarrow$. That would mean that I can fill in any nonzero values for the $a_i$, $b_i$ etc. and will get an MDS code. That cannot be true.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, $c_d$ and $w_1$ are in the same column of $G$.

Comment: @azimut, Do you have any examples that contradict proposition $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: @travan4k I mean, just set $a_i = b_i = 1$ for all $i$. Then the difference of the first rows is a codeword of weight $2$, which is not allowed as soon as $d \geq 3$. Also, $c_d$ and $w_1$ in the same column is equivalent to $n = 2d - 1$, which is true only in the special case $d = k$ of an MDS code.